# PySerial - How to write just the last line of RS232 Serial Port

Tags: pyserial

I tried to write down the values of a temperature measuring device by a serial port. The code is like the following:

```
import time
import serial

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 115200, timeout=1)
RefTemp = open("RefTemp.dat", "w")  

RefTemp.close()                     
sleep = 1/3.



try:
   RefTemp = open("RefTemp.dat", "w")
   while True:
        port.write('s\n')
        time.sleep(sleep)
        localtime   = time.localtime()
        timeString  = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S", localtime)
        newline = port.readline()
        newline = newline[13:21]
        RefTemp.write('%s %s \n' % (newline, timeString))
        print newline
    
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
    RefTemp.close()
```

The problem is, that my output is now two empty lines and then the measured value which results the following content of the .dat file:

> 2016.05.25 13:37:03
>
> 2016.05.25 13:37:03
>
> +022.545 2016.05.25 13:37:03
>
> 2016.05.25 13:37:04
>
> 2016.05.25 13:37:04
>
> +022.544 2016.05.25 13:37:04